# Restore geoserver default layers

Tags: geoserver

I used to work with Geoserver layers.

I am wondering if there is a way to restore the layers given by default after installing Geoserver like topp:states, ...

I have my Geoserver deployed in Apache Tomcat

Comment: You can try a clean install and copy contents of `data_dir` to your existing install, it contains all settings, but passwords etc. will reset to default as well.

Comment: Yes but how can i find a clean install. I tried uninstall and install but everytime i get to geoserver the layers are the same and not restored to default

Comment: You can try to copy a from source code to you installation's `data_dir`, but backup before, I am not sure it works. Check here: https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/tree/main/data/release

Comment: how are you un/installing - a clean install should have the default layers - did you perhaps set the data directory to point somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Default layers are locatede in:

```bash
cd /opt/apache-tomcat-${APACHE_VER}/webapps/geoserver/data/data
```

Or you can install a copy and copy default data. If still not found, try to add this env on install, especial if you use docker:

- SKIP_DEMO_DATA=true # will not install default data
- SKIP_DEMO_DATA=false # will install default data